# Elasticsearch matching with meaning

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a elasticsearch index with fitness plans. I want to match the plan title but doing only text matching leads to a problem.
When searching for "Weight Loss", I see the top result for "Weight Loss" plan but the second result is for "Weight Gain" plan.
How do I not match "Weight Loss" with "Weight Gain"? I'm looking for a way where I understand semantics of the query, rather than just text matching.

Comment: What is the query you are trying to get data, also please add sample document

Answer (score 0):

Use the matching operator `and` if you require the document contains all the words "Weight" and "Loss"

I assume you search with the full text `match` dsl with the word "weight loss". Elasticsearch will analyze your query through [an analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer-anatomy.html) with: character filters, tokenizer, token filter, so it's depend on your setup accordingly.

If you use the default setup, the search term "Weight Loss" will be analyzed and tokenized as "weight" and "loss". Since the [default operator of `match` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) is `OR`, so it will match the document contains either "weight" **OR** "loss", hence your "Weight Gain" document is also captured.

To only match the document contains both words "Weight" **AND** "Loss", you need to explicitly use the operator `and` in your match query.

Your search query should look like

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "<your_document_field_name>": {
                "query": "Weight Loss",
                "operator": "and"
            }            
        }
    }
}
```